# Working with an nvme m.2 on a RPi - Issues with booting from

Tags: boot, clone, nvme

Couple question related to R{i and nvme m.2.

(1) I've been successful(in some cases) getting the Linux system image installed on my RPi on an m.2 drive.  However getting it to boot from it is like walking into the Bates Motel.  There should be a better (easier way).  Is there a simple 'cookbook' type of instructions that a simple minded user could follow and get the desired results - somewhere out there on the web?  PLease point me to a link.

(2) Once I have a suitable m.2 drive that will boot from my nvme, how do I go about easily cloning it?  I have tried clonezilla, dd, Gparted, and none produced the desired results.  When I put the cloned m.2 drive back into the same RPi, the screen just goes blank and nothing boots.  Again, why is this seemingly impossible to get working in Linux for a relative newbie?  I'm already a bald guy, so I don't have any more hair to pull out!

Comment: https://medium.com/@zsmahi/make-ubuntu-server-20-04-boot-from-an-ssd-on-raspberry-pi-4-33f15c66acd4

Comment: this howto explains in detail and is really new: https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-20-04-usb-mass-storage-boot-guide/